# Spark Structured Streaming unable to write parquet data to HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to write data to HDFS from a spark structured streaming code in scala.
But I'm unable to do so due to an error that I failed to understand

On my use case, I'm reading data from a Kafka topic which I want to write on HDFS in parquet format. Everything in my script work well no bug so far.
For doing that I'm using a developement hadoop cluster with 1 namenode and 3 datanodes.

Whatever hadoop configuration I tried I have the same error (2 datanodes, a single node setup and so on ...)

here is the error :

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /test/metadata could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

here is the code I'm using to write data :

```
val query = lbcAutomationCastDf
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("parquet")
    .queryName("lbcautomation")
    .partitionBy("date_year", "date_month", "date_day")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://NAMENODE_IP:8020/test/")
    .option("path", "hdfs://NAMENODE_I:8020/test/")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

The spark scala code work correctly because I can write the data to the server local disk without any error.
I already tried to format the hadoop cluster, it does not change anything

Have you ever deal with this case ?

**UPDATES** :

- Manually push file to HDFS on the cluster work without issues

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your hdfs cluster. Can you push a single file on HDFS using the command line, without failure?

Comment: Yes I tried to put files manualy on HDFS and it work without faillure

Comment: Check out this Hadoop page about the possible reasons for this error: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/CouldOnlyBeReplicatedTo

Comment: I checked everything in the list, on my hadoop cluster everything is ok. But I still got the same error. I can manualy send files but it doesn't work with spark. Any ideas ?